# Capistrano 3 fails on assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I can't deploy my Rails 4 app with strange error on assets:precompile. It's seems like task can't use installed gems. 
In development and production environment on local machine all works perfectly. Part of deploy log:

```
INFO[286bfe45] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.0@gemset do bundle install --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on app.com
DEBUG[286bfe45] Command: cd /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.0@gemset do bundle install --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
INFO[286bfe45] Finished in 2.512 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[6abacc25] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/releases/20150411140229'" 1>&2; false; fi on app.com
DEBUG[6abacc25] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/releases/20150411140229'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[6abacc25] Finished in 0.252 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[6a11bfd6] Finished in 1.650 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG[9a60b6ea] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/releases/20150411140229'" 1>&2; false; fi on app.com
DEBUG[9a60b6ea] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/releases/20150411140229'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[9a60b6ea] Finished in 0.252 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[926b14e1] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.0@gemset do bundle exec rake assets:precompile on app.com
DEBUG[926b14e1] Command: cd /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.0@gemset do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.203678 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed-305f00ea8c7d006b84bb4fae81f9560f.png
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.230319 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/projects/project-item-engine-rails-879f2b31347734136f7381f19bb9f6a3.png
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.233698 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/projects/projects-list-header-57d1dcc1cc60e2eb39438cb1845a9aa2.jpg
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.236956 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/rails-31b23f13156504238438fdd89afe6fd6.png
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.237889 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/sprites/blog-color-fd3e21aa29714c4881b34b34b4980ba9.png
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.284081 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/application-659c280b13b0f592813748b6abb50b74.js
DEBUG[926b14e1]         I, [2015-04-11T14:02:51.311349 #18205]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/public/assets/front-9b21c4b4182f885f99929c6f71639a44.js
DEBUG[926b14e1]         rake aborted!
DEBUG[926b14e1]         Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'sprites-sprite'.
DEBUG[926b14e1]           (in /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/app/assets/stylesheets/static.css.scss:96)
DEBUG[926b14e1]         /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/app/assets/stylesheets/static.css.scss:96:in `sprites-sprite'
DEBUG[926b14e1]         /var/www/app/releases/20150411140229/app/assets/stylesheets/static.css.scss:96
DEBUG[926b14e1]         /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:253:in `visit_mixin'
DEBUG[926b14e1]         /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
```

I think that problem is in placing gems. First line of log telling me that all gems in /var/www/app/shared/bundle and it's truth — they are really there. But if I run `rvm 2.2.0@gemset do gem list` as deploy user I don't see installed gems in list:

```
deployer@server:/var/www/app/current$ rvm 2.2.0@gemset do gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.8.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

And when I run `bundle` from app's folder I can see a full list of installed gems:

```
deployer@server:/var/www/app/current$ bundle
Using rake 10.4.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1
Using compass 0.12.7
Using breakpoint 2.0.7
Using compass-rails 2.0.0
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.2
/* removed some lines to save space */
Using rails 4.1.8
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using uglifier 2.5.0
Using unicorn 4.8.3
Bundle complete! 39 Gemfile dependencies, 87 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into /var/www/app/shared/bundle.
```

I use rvm for development and production in single-user mode and some my files here:

```
# deploy.rb
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'App'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:app/app.com.git'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/app'

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.0@gemset'
set :unicorn_env, 'production'
set :rails_env, :production
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/scp.yml}

set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
namespace :deploy do

    desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
        invoke 'unicorn:restart'
    end

    after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
        end
    end

after :publishing, :restart
end
```

Capfile

```
# Capfile
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
require 'whenever/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Front.css.scss set as precompiled in application.rb

```
# front.css.scss
@import "compass";
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "sprites/*.png";
@include all-sprites-sprites;
@import "breakpoint";
$breakpoint-tiny : 0 660px;

@import "static";
```

And for example static.css.scss:

```css
/* static.css.scss */
.blog {
    @include sprites-sprite(blog-gray);
    &:hover {
        @include sprites-sprite(blog-color);
    }
}
```

If I remove all mixins from static.css.scss deploy will finished successfully.

Comment: Are you able to run `rake assets:precompile` on local machine successfully? It says `sprites-sprite` is missing

Comment: @RAJ thank you for advice, I've got the same error! Now I know that's it doesn't depend from capistrano. Have you  any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: It says `sprites-sprite` is missing module. Are you using some gem for sprites? Make sure you have all required files/modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, it wasn't related to capistrano or even rvm. 
I use two layouts for my app: front.html.slim and admin.html.slim, each with a dedicated stylesheet: `front.css` and `admin.css`.

In `front.css.scss` I was using the following (sass) syntax:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
```

While `admin.css.scss` used Sprocket's syntax:

```
/*
 *= require base
 *= require posts
 *= require projects
```

The `assets:precompile` task finished successfully after I changed `admin.css.scss` to actual sass syntax:

```
 @import "base";
 @import "posts";
 @import "projects";
```

Thanx @RAJ for your advice.

Comment: Just to clarify, you changed admin.css.scss to:     "@import base", "@import posts" "@import projects" ...?

Comment: @PeterBlack yes. From compass gem docs: Don't use *= require something within your SCSS or SASS files. You're gonna have a bad time.